# a predicate to filter out similar objects by an attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I"m performing a regular `NSFetchRequest` without any predicate to fetch 100 managed objects (flights), each `Flight` entity has an attribute of type `NSString` named (flightCode) and this attribute is not unique, so 2 flight objects may have the same flightCode .
However, I want to fetch all flight objects filtering out flights that have the same flightCode by taking only one flight from similarities, i.e.

if the fetch request returned 5 flights as follows:

flight1: flightCode = `ABC`

flight2: flightCode = `AA`

flight3: flightCode = `ABC`

flight4: flightCode = `ABC`

flight5: flightCode = `DEF`

then the fetch request must filter out any two of the 3 flights that have the flightCode `ABC` and take only any random one of these 3.

what is the required `NSPredicate` for this filtering ?

p.s. flights: 1, 3 & 4 may be different in other attributes, i.e. flight1's name may be different from flight3's name.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the unique flight codes or do you want a random `Flight` instance from each set of equal flight codes?

Comment: @BarryWark I'm looking for a random Flight instance from each set of equal flight codes.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish what you want with an `NSFetchRequest`. What you're looking for is some variation of a group-by operation. In Core Data, that has to be done in-memory. Looks like you're using an `NSArrayController`.

Comment: @BarryWark can you elaborate more or show a piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of all distinct flight codes, this may do what you want:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Flight"
    inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity.name];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[ entity.propertiesByName[@"flightCode"] ];
```

Note that `returnsDistinctResults` only works if `propertiesToFetch` is set, and `propertiesToFetch` only works if `resultType` is `NSDictionaryResultType`.

#### REVISED

If you want full `Flight` objects, but only one for each distinct flight code, I don't think you can do that directly.  Perhaps you can ask for both the object ID and the flight code, group by flight code, and take the minimum object ID, to get one object ID for each flight code.  Then you can turn those object IDs into full objects one by one using `objectForID:` on the managed object context.  I would try something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Flight"
    inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSExpressionDescription *objectIDProperty = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
objectIDProperty.name = @"objectID";
objectIDProperty.expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:"
    arguments:@[ [NSExpression expressedForEvaluatedObject] ]];
objectIdProperty.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

NSAttributeDescription *flightCodeProperty = entity.propertiesByName[@"flightCode"];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity.name];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[ flightCodeProperty, objectIDProperty ];

request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[ flightCodeProperty ];
```

I cribbed a lot of that from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792331/77567).  I have no idea if it works, or if I'm even on the right track.  If it runs at all, but doesn't quite give the right output, remember that you can see the SQL it's executing by adding `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` as a command-line argument.

Comment: I'm using this fetch request inside a fetchedResultsController, i know that I will lose most of its functionality (like observing for controller changes) but is it possible to call objectForID inside the fetchedResultsController directly, if yes, HOW ?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible.  You'd have to set the `expressionResultType` of `objectIDProperty` to something that makes it return a full object, but [there is no such type](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAttributeType).

Comment: If fetching all the flights and filtering in code is too expensive, you'll probably have to denormalize your model.  For example, give the `Flight` entity a boolean attribute named `flightCodeRepresentative`, and make sure whenever you add or remove flights that exactly one flight has it set to true for each flight code.  Then fetching exactly one flight per flight code becomes trivial.

Comment: the problem that flights are saved to the persistent store automatically with RestKit mapper, and yes, filtering with code is kinda expensive

Comment: do you advise me to write a direct sqlite query for this case ?

Comment: You should not access a Core Data store directly with sqlite.  If you want to try to denormalize your model in the way that I suggested, and you need help doing it, you should post a question to that effect, explaining exactly how you are using RestKit to update your store.

Comment: .. make sure whenever you add or remove flights that exactly one flight has it .. this means that I have to check at each insert that the current Flight's flightCode exists among other flights records, isn't this expensive too at the inserting level ?

Comment: You can pre-populate an cache with a single `NSFetchRequest`.  The cache is simply an `NSMutableSet` containing all known flight codes (since presumably each flight code has at least one flight).  When you insert a new flight, check the cache for its flight code.  If the cache lacks the flight code, set the `flightCodeRepresentative` property to true on the new flight and add the code to the cache.

Comment: after i commented out objectIDProperty Expression Description the run time error disappears, it sounds that i can't run more than 1 expression at the same fetch request ?

Comment: I suspect the problem is simply that the `min:` function cannot be applied to object IDs, and that you will have to go with a different solution like the denormalization I suggested earlier.

Comment: yes exactly it's the min function does not apply to object IDs, I've started a new SO question about checking against a condition at saving time with RestKit. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333424/restkit-0-2x-checking-for-a-condition-at-inserting-time

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunately I have no experience with RestKit.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

youll want to make a `NSMuteableArray` for all of your flights and then a separate `NSMuteableArray` to keep track of which elements you have already seen

pseudocode:

```
NSMuteablearray flights
NSMuteablearray alreadySeen


for (item in flights) {
if (alreadySeen containsObject:item)
     flights removeObject:item
else
     alreadySeen addObject:item

}
```

Comment: I'm not asking objective-c I'm asking about a predicate, by the way the fetch request will be inside a fetchedResultsController getter