# RestKit 0.2x: checking for a condition at inserting time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I have setup my project to use restKit with core data (1 entity) without problems, however, I intentionally left 1 boolean attribute without mapping for some app design purpose. I want to set this boolean according to a condition related to the current record being inserted, i.e. if this record contains a property that equals xxx then set this boolean to YES.
how can I do something like this with `restKit 0.2x` at the time of inserting that record in the persistent store.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `NSManagedObject` subclass, override `willSave` and implement your check and set your Boolean values. This will ensure that everything is up to date before RestKit completes the mapping process.