# Retrieve Object ID from a fetch request on an abstract entity with a group by clause

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm implementing a search in an iOS app (targeting iOS 8 and up), and have a set of entities that store search terms for other objects. The search term entities have an abstract parent. Each concrete search term entity has a relationship to the object it relates to (an object can have many search terms). This way I can run a fetch request against the abstract parent search term entity, and through each concrete result get to the object that matches. As an example:

[image]

I'm then making a request like this to find matches for a given string:

```
NSString *text = @"query";
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AbstractSearchTerm"];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"term CONTAINS[cd] %@", text];

NSSortDescriptor *boostSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"boost" ascending:NO];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[boostSortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The fetch request is then fed to a `NSFetchedResultsController` which drives a table view of search results. This works well enough except that I get multiple results for each `Category`, `Tag` etc. because of the to-many relationship to the search term (I can't use a to-one relationship because some results need to be be boosted over others). So I thought to somehow group the results by the actual entity that they relate to.

Firstly - if there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without having to get into grouping then I'm all ears. Perhaps something using subqueries.. Otherwise, here's where it gets messy!

In order to group results I obviously need something to group on; I have a unique identifier for each record (e.g. one from my remote API) which I can denormalise to a property on `AbstractSearchTerm`, so I can use that. I modified my fetch request like so:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AbstractSearchTerm" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entityDescription propertiesByName];

NSString *text = @"query";
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AbstractSearchTerm"];

// ...

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[entityProperties[@"uniqueIdentifier"], entityProperties[@"term"], entityProperties[@"boost"]];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[entityProperties[@"uniqueIdentifier"], entityProperties[@"term"], entityProperties[@"boost"]];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error = nil;
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

And I get results, but I don't have the objectID to work back to the actual search object, and thus to the matched relation. So I thought to also retrieve the objectID. There's a way to do that, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956406/core-data-how-to-get-nsmanagedobjects-objectid-when-nsfetchrequest-returns-nsd), but when I try it like so:

```
NSExpressionDescription* objectIdDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
objectIdDesc.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

// ...

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[objectIdDesc, entityProperties[@"uniqueIdentifier"], entityProperties[@"term"], entityProperties[@"boost"]];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[objectIdDesc, entityProperties[@"uniqueIdentifier"], entityProperties[@"term"], entityProperties[@"boost"]];
```

I get this error:

`Invalid keypath expression ((<NSExpressionDescription: 0x7f9e89454e50>), name objectID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier objectID, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}) passed to setPropertiesToFetch:`

Which I can't get around. It may be a bug in Core Data, or perhaps that approach isn't valid when the fetch request has a group by clause. Without a way to get back to a concrete entity instance I'm stuck. Since I'm going to be querying an amount of records in at least the tens of thousands I don't want to be making too many queries or putting a lot of data in memory, so until now I've ruled out storing results in an array and filtering them in code (I'd prefer to keep using NSFetchedResultsController and batch results). If anyone has any advice on where I could go from here I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to store searches the user can compose and persist them within your Core Data model. To create entities describing this search information is a valid approach.

However, I think that your idea to then link these search objects with actual data object is not very good from a design perspective. The data objects should not be burdened with searching functionality (especially not on a data model level). Thus, your search modeling should be independent from your data, i.e. without direct relationships between those two groups of entities.

There is really no advantage having direct relationships. Both constructing and executing a fetch request, and pulling down entities in a relationship have the same persistent store overhead, so it just adds unnecessary complexity.

Instead, have the search related entities describe the search. I think that you can achieve that quite simply **without** parent and child entities. I would think that all need is perhaps a to-many relationship for subpredicates, but maybe not even that. All search relevant information can be coded in string attributes. The entire search model could be as simple as:

```
Search <----->> Condition
```

I think you can achieve all you want (including grouping, counting etc.) with this very much simplified setup. Also, you do not have to worry about the result types any more, just fetch `NSManagedObejct`s.

Comment: You're right that it's a better design if the data entities are unaware of search entities. Would you mind validating what I think you're suggesting: I remove that relationship and the abstract/child relationship on search entities - and instead store the entity class and an identifier on a Search record which I can then use as criteria in subsequent fetch requests? Then my initial fetch request is for Search entities, with a predicate that establishes at least one Condition object related to the search object matches? That makes sense to me, just want to check before I start refactoring :)

Comment: What you describe seems really overkill. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to first do a search within searches and then search the data based on the found search -- quite absurd. I was more thinking along the line of a simple "saved searches" feature found in some applications - so without the searching within the searches. You just fetch the saved searches once and then just fetch the data based on the search the user selects.

Comment: That's not quite it - I'm storing a list of terms to match against, like how a FTS engine would create n-grams and such (that's how I imagined the 'Condition' entity, with the 'Search' one pointing to a specific data record). The search has to be text input driven due to the number of records - the sort of thing you'd use a full text search for but Core Data only supports CONTAINS - so asking the user to select a result isn't feasible. I suspect it'd be better to not do this in Core Data at all and use SQLite directly or something, but that's not an option for now.

Comment: Very confusing. I don't think Core Data has the constraints you mention. It seems that this is unrelated to the original data model design problem. In my mind, the `Search` entity is simply a collection of conditions, comparable to predicates that can be strung together to create a search predicate. Perhaps it would make sense to ask a new, more detailed question about this subtopic.

Comment: Yes - if I can achieve what I want by changing the model so I don't have to worry about grouping entities then I'm happy - from the predicate side of things I think I know what I'm doing. Based on what you've suggested I'll refactor my model and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to added following to get ObjectID

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType
```

Comment: Thanks - a fetch request using a group clause has to be of a `NSDictionaryResultType` result type though.